# Problem issuing \egroup ("}") from Lua

Tags: luatex, boxes, lua

I would like to define a command using Lua that will start and end a `\savebox` depending on if it is starred or not. Let's call this command `\switchcolumn`.

Here is the code (the first `\switchcolumn` that starts the box is substituted with the literal text, since it is irrelevant to the question):

```
\documentclass[11pt, paper = B5]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xparse}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{luacode}
    dofile(kpse.find_file("mwe.lua"))
\end{luacode}

\NewDocumentCommand{\switchcolumn}{}{\directlua{SwitchColumn()}}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\aaa}
\savebox{\aaa}[0.5\textwidth] {
Hello World!
\switchcolumn

\end{document}
```

`mwe.lua`:

```lua
function SwitchColumn()
    tex.cprint(2, "}")
end
```

It doesn't work. The closing curly bracket doesn't end up in the TeX's engine input:

```
Runaway argument?
{ Hello World! \switchcolumn \par \end {document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \@isavebox.
```

I tried `tex.print`, `tex.sprint`, it's all the same.

How to set things right?

Comment: it isn't that clear what you want to do. Your Lua is never called at all as tex is scanning for the end of the argument and will hit the end of file looking for the `}`. tex macros are not expanded while scanning for arguments.

Comment: perhaps you would be better to use `lrbox` environment rather than`\savebox` and then write out `\end{lrbox}`  (although you would not need Lua for that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact Lua form of your function disn't matter as macros and commands are not executed while TeX is scanning for arguments, so the end of file is reached looking for a closing `}` and `\switchcolumn` is never expanded.

You could use the environment form `lrbox` but that doesn't have a width argument so I re-use the box in `\makebox` to set the width.

[image]

Lua (although you could use a tex definition here more easily)

```
function SwitchColumn()
tex.print('\\end{lrbox}')
end
```

tex

```
\documentclass[11pt, paper = B5]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xparse}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

% over complicated:
%\begin{luacode}
%    dofile(kpse.find_file("mwe.lua"))
%\end{luacode}
\directlua{require 'mwe'}

\NewDocumentCommand{\switchcolumn}{}{\directlua{SwitchColumn()}}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\aaa}
\begin{lrbox}{\aaa}
Hello World!
\switchcolumn


X\makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\unhbox\aaa}X
\end{document}
```

Comment: "although you could use a tex definition here more easily" — obviously I want to do something more, than the mwe shows. Also I can debug Lua in a real debugger, with breakpoints and everything. TeX programming is only for real Jedi. I am an ordinary guy.